# Why do I get an error when using bluetooth in react native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am making a simple application in expo react native to scan and connect to devices via bluetooth, the problem is the errors that it throws at me.
I am using the following library: https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx

In android I get this error:
[image]

In IOS:[image]

Part of my code:

```
    import { BleManager } from 'react-native-ble-plx';

    const manager = new BleManager();
    useEffect(()=>{
      manager.startDeviceScan(UUIDs, null, (error, device) => {
        console.log("Scanning...");
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return;
        }
        console.log(device.name)
      });
   }, [manager])
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply but it seems that expo does not support Bluetooth

EDIT:
https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/bluetooth-1
You can use Expo with react-native-ble-plx

Comment: Could you provide any references to support this statement?

Comment: I may have said something wrong. When I did my research, there was no answer
https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/bluetooth-1